# Free app to run task of visiting a url

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

I need to run an .asp webpage on my site every 40 minutes.
Does anyone recommend a free web-based app that I can enter in my url and it will visit the url every 30 - 60 mins?

preferably one without an annoying reg form :)

thanks

Comment: Really? Negative one? Many people use a shared host that does not include Schedule Task. Hence the reason for this.

Comment: @aron: You got a downvote because it was posted on the wrong website. Also "please find me a tool" questions are not very well-liked. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a server uptime monitoring service such as [SiteUptime](http://www.siteuptime.com/) or [HyperSpin](http://www.hyperspin.com).

Another alternative is to run something from your own machine, or from a machine on which you have shell (command-line) access.

On your client machine, you can use crontab (Linux) or Scheduled Task (Windows) to execute [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) or [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) at regular intervals, or you can write a script that does the same.  Either one will fetch a page/file from a web server, although their usefulness doesn't end there.  Both are also available as native command-line programs on most platforms.

The nice thing about using crontab/Scheduled Task is that you don't have to worry about keeping the program open; it'll just run when needed, and when you reboot you don't have to remember to run anything because it's already scheduled to run at the predefined times.

If you have shell access on the web server (you might have it and don't know it, or might be able to get it), you might be able to set up a crontab directly on the server.  In the past, I've also asked a hosting company to set up a crontab for me when my website was on a restricted server that didn't allow customers to directly schedule tasks in crontab.

Comment: +1 for crontab/scheduled tasks with curl/wget. This is definitely the best way to do this. Ideally such a cronjob should run on the same machine as the website, but if that's not possible it could run on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this sort of thing is configured at the host level, and not by using a service.  Are you running on a virtual server or shared hosting?  If virtual server, you can use a scheduled task, if shared hosting, you can usually poke around the admin interface and find something that allows you to schedule a job.

Comment: Groovetrain - really? you don't think I already looked in the site's admin panel?

Comment: @aron: Being snide will not aid you in getting the free help you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Pingdom](http://Pingdom.com) for these types of things. Yes you have to register, but it is free after all.